Monomorphisms in $Loc$ need not be one-to-one
Let $Loc$ be the category of locales, why a monomorphsim in $Loc$ need not be one-to-one? I know how to prove that a monomorphism is one-to-one in the category Set but I don't know why the same proof does not work in $Loc$, is it because a one element set is not conisedred as a locale?
Here Is a single element a Lattice? it is said that a one element set is a lattice.
Could you give me an example of a monomorphism in $Loc$ that is not one-to-one?

Also I've just remembered locales have "opposite" directions. A locale homomorphism from singleton to $L$ is actually a frame homomorphism $L$ to singleton, and there is only one of these! It doesn't distinguish elements

I see, there is only one localic map from singleton to $L$.  So the proof used  ins Set does not work in $Loc$.

What do you mean by "one-to-one" in the category of locales? It's clear what a one-to-one morphism of frames should be but locales are the opposite category.

Monomorphisms in the category of frames (which correspond to epimorphisms in $Loc$, the opposite category) must be one-to-one (or injective). Must epimorphisms in the category of frames (corresponding to monomorphisms in the opposite category $Loc$) be onto (or surjective)?

@GeoffreyTrang Why an epimorphism in $Frm$  need not be surjective? An example?

What is not right in this proof: let $h : L \to M$ a locale homomorphism that is not  one-one. Then there are
$a, b \in L, a \not = b$ such that $h(a) = h(b)$. Consider the locale $3 = {0 < c < 1}$ and
the maps $f, g : 3 \to L$ sending $0$ to $0$, $1$ to $1$, and $f (c) = a$, $g(c) = b$.  $f$ and $g$ are locales homomorphisms, and $hf = hg$ while $f \not = g$.

@Catalio13 Complements in distributive lattices are unique if they exist. So, the inclusion of the Sierpinski topology ${\emptyset,{1},{0,1}}$ in the discrete topology ${\emptyset,{0},{1},{0,1}}$ on ${0,1}$ is an epimorphism in the category of distributive lattices, and in particular, also in the category of frames.
